# PowerBI table published outside/partitioned from the original semantic model in the workspace

Tags: powerbi, power-automate, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-api, powerbi-datagateway

I have semantic model that is significantly large. And I added a table to this report which needs to be refreshed periodically. (planning to refresh via power automate)

My question is can I refresh just this single table, without refreshing the whole semantic model? if so how?

(I am new to this PowerBI world)

My ideas/brainstorming...

1. can I publish this semantic model as two pieces, one just the table and the rest as the second one.
2. Can power automate refresh just one table out of a dataset?

Pour in your suggestions!! thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot, the whole dataset refreshes. Options: Look at having a [Composite Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-composite-models) where your new table isn't in your semantic model, but adjacent to it. - Or - . Look at having the new table in a data source that supports DirectQuery. For example, you could use a Dataflow for your new table. [Use DirectQuery with dataflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-directquery).